# React & Apollo, how to set authorization header when user logs in?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Assume we create a client like this initially

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri:'https://api.com/graphql'
})
```

Initially this api has some mutations like `signIn` and `signUp` exposed, that don't require authentication.

Somewhere down the line user signs in and receives an auth token. This token now needs to be set on our apollo `client` as a header i.e.

```
headers: {
   Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
}
```

Is it possible to somehow update `client` "on the fly" to apply this header in order for future api requests to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/) you can do this :

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

**UPDATE**

You can update your token using 'apollo-boost'

> Note that the above example is using ApolloClient from the apollo-client package. Headers can still be modified using ApolloClient from the apollo-boost package, but since apollo-boost doesn't allow the HttpLink instance it uses to be modified, headers have to be passed in as a config parameter:

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  request: (operation) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Mmm, this still falls under initial setup? What if client is already created and after 2 min user logs in, is it possible to update already created client?